# Wordpress Woocommerce How to enable lighbox for product category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im in searching for a few days and try to find a hook how to enable lightbox for Product Category page , i found only how to enable it for Single product page.
Im using last version of WooCommerce and also have used `add_theme_support`

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
```

Here its some screens of what im trying to do:
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfsFl.png)
its how it should look, and here is lighbox preview. 
[Lighbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPF6l.jpg)
And here is a screen of how it looks at this moment.
[Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv0ad.png)

Ty.

Comment: you mean example screens how should it work ?

Comment: Im still searching for answer (